# Xamarin Android, Xamarin Forms orientation change

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Android app that use the Xamarin Forms UI framework.
I detect the screen orientation and want to only allow portrait and landscape for a specific Page but portrait only for all other pages.

I tried to call RequestOrientation but that force the orientation to stay the same and doesn't fire my orientation change notification again.

Comment: Do you allow other orientations than portrait orientation in Android solution properties?

Answer (score 2):

Have a static property in your App.Xaml.cs

```
public static bool IsPortraitOnly { get; set; }
```

Set it to `false` in all pages and to `true` in the page you want it to be Portrait only.

In your `MainActivity` in android project, override the method `OnConfigurationChanged` :

```
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        //using to prevent the OnCreate from firing when rotating or screen size is changing
        if (App.IsPortraitOnly)
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            newConfig.Orientation = Orientation.Portrait;
        }
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

The following are the available orientation values in android :

```
public enum Orientation
{
    Landscape = 2,
    Portrait = 1,
    Square = 3,
    Undefined = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether you’re in portrait or landscape mode is pretty easy:

```
 static bool IsPortrait(Page p) { return p.Width < p.Height; }
```

you can use sizeChanged event.The SizeChanged event seems to get called exactly once as the user goes from portrait to landscape mode

```
 SizeChanged += (sender, e) => Content = IsPortrait(this) ? portraitView : landscapeView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

If you write code on the code side, portrait mode is maintained.