# 'OnSizeAllocated' is not being called when I rotate the android emulator to change the orientation to Landscape mode or Potrait mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I want to change the page layout when the device orientation changes. But for this, I first need to be notified when ever the orientation changes.

I have used Page's 'SizeChanged' event and it works fine when I rotate the screen in ios simulator. But this is not being called for android emulator.

I also tried using OnSizeAllocated method, it again doesn't get called for android emulator but works fine for ios simulator.

```
public LoginPage()    
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width,double height)
{
  base.OnSizeAllocated(width,height); 
  //
  //
}
```

This is the emulator that I'm using:-

[image]

OnSizeAllocated() should be called a number of times. But it only gets called once when the app starts (For android emulator).

How do I make it work or is there any other way to get notified when the emulator orientation is changed?

Comment: You could refer to this code that used `OnConfigurationChanged` in `mainactivity`https://stackoverflow.com/a/41270695/10627299

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Yeah I'm currently making use of OnConfigurationChanged.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Yes. It works now. I haven't changed anything but both SizeChanged and OnSizeAllocated are being called without any issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't changed anything in the code and there is no new xamarin update but today when I tried both the methods are working just fine.

So for me I guess restarting Visual studio, cleaning and building projects made it work.

Answer (score 4):

The Forms' `OnSizeAllocated` event is coupled to the Android Activity's `OnConfigurationChanged`.

So if `OnConfigurationChanged` is not being called, it could be any of these three things:

1. Is you device|emulator set to auto-rotate? Pull down the quick setting and ensure that rotation is enabled.

[image]

2. You removed the `ConfigChanges.Orientation` from your Activity's attributes.

MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label ~~~~~, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

3. You are forcing your Android application / activity into a single orientation (via manifest, attributes and/or native Android code)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

I checked with your point 1 and point 2. I have the same settings and Android Activity's 'OnConfigurationChanged is being called but 'OnSizeAllocated' doesn't get called.

So currently I put my code in OnConfigurationChanged and making use of it.

And I'm new to xamarin forms and I don't understand point 3...